# What is "python-fwf" engine in pandas read_csv() method and when to use it?

Tags: python, pandas

I was going through the pandas documentation, and going through read_csv() method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), I saw that the latest version (2.2 stable) mentions only 3 engines:

```
engine: {‘c’, ‘python’, ‘pyarrow’}, optional
```

However, in my PyCharm (with pandas version 2.2.0), I can see that a fourth engine is mentioned as well, which is `python-fwf`

[image]

I have searched in pandas documentation, but could not find any information about this.
Can someone please explain in what scenarios this should be used?

Note: I know that there is a `pandas.read_fwf()` which can be used to read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame. Is the engine connected to this scenario? If yes, why we should use `read_csv()` with `python-fwf` engine instead of `read_fwf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: I know that there is a `pandas.read_fwf()` which can be used to read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame. Is the engine connected to this scenario?

Absolutely. [`read_fwf`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f538741432edf55c6b9fb5d0d496d2dd1d7c2457/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L1451-L1563) defines this [engine](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f538741432edf55c6b9fb5d0d496d2dd1d7c2457/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L1557) as default:

```
# PythonParser is used for python engine
# FixedWidthFieldParser is used for python-fwf
kwds["engine"] = "python-fwf"
```

`python-fwf` engine is part of [`CSVEngine`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f538741432edf55c6b9fb5d0d496d2dd1d7c2457/pandas/_typing.py#L407):

```
CSVEngine = Literal["c", "python", "pyarrow", "python-fwf"]
```

That's why you can see that in your IDE because `CSVEngine` has been expanded to `Literal[...]`.

However the [documentation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f538741432edf55c6b9fb5d0d496d2dd1d7c2457/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L186-L189) hides this engine for `read_table` and `read_csv` because it's not relevant for these functions:

```
engine : {{'c', 'python', 'pyarrow'}}, optional
    Parser engine to use. The C and pyarrow engines are faster, while the python engine
    is currently more feature-complete. Multithreading is currently only supported by
    the pyarrow engine.
```

> Can someone please explain in what scenarios this should be used?

None :-) Only the documentation is (should be) authoritative.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Corralien. Guess I should have taken that extra step and searched in the code as well! Appreciate your help with clear & concise answer!